# MPI+OpenACC: How #pragma acc host_data use_device() works?

Tags: gpu, mpi, mpich, openacc

```
  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST], recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST]) 
  for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) send_buf[i] = phi[j][i];

  #pragma acc host_data use_device(send_buf, recv_buf)
  {
    MPI_Sendrecv (send_buf, iend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procR[1], 0, recv_buf, iend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procR[1], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  }

  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST], recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) phi[j+1][i] = recv_buf[i];
```

I need this portion of the code to run on the GPU and I'd like also the MPI message to involve only the device. For this purpose I saw that`#pragma acc host_data use_device()` should be perfect but the compiler seems not to see it (-Minfo=accel) and I get an error running the application:

**BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES

PID 36444 RUNNING AT Inspiron-7501

EXIT CODE: 139

CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES

YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES

YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault (signal 11)**

Removing it it works well, but it's slow:

```
  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST], recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST]) 
  for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) send_buf[i] = phi[j][i];

  #pragma acc update self(send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  MPI_Sendrecv (send_buf, iend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procR[1], 0, recv_buf, iend+1, MPI_DOUBLE, procR[1], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  #pragma acc update device(recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])

  #pragma acc parallel loop present(phi[:ny_tot][:nx_tot], send_buf[:NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST], recv_buf[NX_GLOB+2*NGHOST])
  for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++) phi[j+1][i] = recv_buf[i];
```

Comment: What MPI are you using?  Does it have CUDA Aware MPI support enabled?  The error seems to indicate that it's not.

Comment: @MatColgrove I'm using MPICH. How can I check that CUDA Aware MPI is enabled?

Comment: @MatColgrove I see that there's a configure options of MPICH --with-device=name, but nothing directly related to CUDA

Comment: @MatColgrove I tried to run ./configure --with-cuda=/opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/20.7/cuda but it seems not effective, it displays: "checking cuda.h usability... no
checking cuda.h presence... no
checking for cuda.h... no"

Comment: We do ship a pre-built OpenMPI that does have CUDA Aware MPI enabled.  So you might try it, at least to see to confirm that's the issue.  I don't build MPICH myself so don't know details, but let me send a note to the person that does our MPI builds and see if he has idea for you.

Comment: I talked with Chris.  He doesn't build MPICH but as far as we can tell MPICH doesn't support CUDA Aware MPI.  OpenMPI and MVAPICH do, and I saw a post which looks like Cray added it to their MPICH build, but I'm not seeing anything on mpich.org which says that they support it.

Comment: @MatColgrove Ok, thank you very much. I''l try with OpenMPI.